# ShapeDrawable and LinearLayout not working as expected

Tags: android, android-layout, shapedrawable

[image]

My code:

```
<LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="30dp"
       android:background="@drawable/myCustomShapeDrawable"
       android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <View 
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="0.4px"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="#cccccc"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see, the first problem is that the line's height is not matching the LinearLayout's height, despite having "match_parent" at its height attribute.
The second problem is that it doesnt align itself in the center of the LinearLayout.

Comment: What is your custom drawable shape.

Comment: post your drawable shape

Comment: My bad, the padding in the drawable was a few dp high, resulting in a bit of "cutting".
However, I still can't figure out why it doesnt align in the center of the layout.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This below code will work according to the requirement:

```
 <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="30dp"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:background="@drawable/myCustomShapeDrawable"
           android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <View 
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="0.4px"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="#cccccc"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```